# symfony: sfDoctrineGuardPlugin: doesn't redirect to the referer page

Tags: symfony1

I have just crate a new sf 1.3 project, installed sfDGP and activated the security on my web app so when i write an URL the authentication form appears.

The problem: after logging the web app is not redirected to the referrer
URL but to the root URL.

These are my steps:

- I call the URL "http://rs3.localhost/frontend_dev.php/usuario"
- The auth form appears.
- If i write var_dump($user->getReferer($request->getReferer())); inside
  the signin action this is showed:

"http://rs3.localhost/frontend_dev.php/"

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: If you create new projects you should really use 1.4. The difference between 1.3 is minor but 1.4 is a long term support release.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, anyway I've tried it using sf 1.4 and the result is the same.

Comment: I noticed the same behavior, what happens when you refresh the login screen? I had the feeling that the referrer was always one URL behind.

Comment: @tirengarfio did you ever solve this? I'm getting this issue now.